# Enterprise search platform vs General purpose search

Tags: apache, search, solr, lucene, full-text-search

I have a question about Solr. It is described as an enterprise search platform. Are there Enterprise oriented search platforms and general purpose search platforms? Can't you just use Solr for example to build a general purpose search engine? If there is such a distinction what are the major differences between them?

Answer (score 1):

Enterprise is a vague term tacked on to things to say "Yes, you can totally use this in professional projects, it's super good".  It's baloney, in short.  When reading the front page of a software product (or any product really), I find it useful to ignore all adjectives and adverbs, which makes that first sentence on the [Solr page](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) read:  "Solr is the search platform from the Apache Lucene project."

Don't know why I don't get hired to write ad copy.

I think it would be fair to say that Solr is a general purpose search server, sure (depending on what general purpose entails to you, of course).  It indexes data, allows you to search it, and provides a lot of tools to do that in the way the best suits your data and users.

Answer (score 0):

The term **Search** is overloaded with lots of semantics. It is often used to denote/describe either an action, a function or a technology. But more important wit respect to the question is the fact that there are two common kind of "search projects" which are `Web Search` and `Enterprise Search` projects.

**Web Search** is typically about indexing content from one kind of content source (*Web Servers*) serving content in html format. Most often it's only about public content and document level security is not an issue. A typical example for this kind of solution is Google's Web Search, but most full-text `Site Search` solutions can also be seen as good examples of this category. For a basic solution a crawler , an html markup removal tool and an indexing library and some "glue" is sufficient. Apache Nutch or Apache Solr and ElasticSearch in combination with a web crawler are good candidates to be used for implementing these kind of solutions.

**Enterprise Search** is typically about integrating content in various formats from multiple content sources. A typical example for this kind of solution are corporate intranets, but `Search Based Applications` often also fall into this category. Those solutions typically come with additional requirements such as support for document level security, advanced linguistics, metadata extraction, data mappings and enrichments, synonyms etc. The projects are more complex and a more complex technology stack is needed. While Apache Solr or ElasticSearch can both be used, a lot of the required functionality is not part of the standard download and needs to be developed or integrated as part of the project. But for both - Apache Solr and ElasticSearch - there are also commercial distributions available that already expand the functionality of the standard download into the direction of `Enterprise Search`. Other good alternatives are commercial search engines.

I agree with @femtoRgon that Solr:

- **is a good** General Purpose Search Platform
- **and not** an Enterprise Search Platform
- but an Enterprise Search Platform **can be built** with Solr

Answer (score 0):

Solr is a search platform that can be customized for either general purpose search or for Enterprise Search solutions. As suggested by Daniel in the previous comments, ESearch application is used specifically for an enterprise/organization to search for the organizations internal data and also in some cases can search external content as well but only related to the organization. Enterprises generally use various systems which are either internally developed or by a vendor and the ESearch application should be able to connect to the internal systems and index the content including the different file types, metadata and importantly security that is associated with each and every document from those systems.

To conclude, Solr is a Search system which can be used to index and search content as a general or as a ESearch application for a organization.